# How do I call a PHP function using AJAX, and get the returned value?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to call a specific function from my `database.php` file, and get the returned value. Here I am trying to do this:

js:

```
function submit_verification_code(){
$.ajax({
url: "database.php",
type: "post",
data: ({
    'code': code_entered,
}),
dataType:"text",
context: this,
success : function(response) {
    console.log('RESPONSE: ' + response);
    //OPTIONAL_FUNCTION_TO_DO_SOMETHING_WITH_THE_RESPONSE(response);
},
error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    //OPTIONAL_FUNCTION_TO_DO_SOMETHING_WITH_THE_ERROR(jqXHR);
    console.log(errorThrown);
}
});
}
```

database.php

```
 if(isset($_POST['code'])){
    does_code_match($_POST['code']);
 }
 function does_code_match($code){

    connect();
            die('test');
    $sql = 'select * from emailstobeverified where email=';
    $sql .= "'" . $_SESSION['email'] . "'";
    $sql .= ' and verification_code=';
    $sql .= $code;
    $sql .= ';';
    $count = query($sql)->num_rows;

    die(strval($count));
    disconnect();
    echo strval($count);
    exit;
    //Once you've outputted, make sure nothing else happens
 }
```

`does_code_match` function executes, and the console log prints `<br />` when `console.log("RESPONSE" + response)` is called. But I want it to print the value of `$count`

EDIT:

There is a problem with `connect()` function. If I call `die('test')` just before calling `connect()`, it returns a response! It says "hello world" in the console. If I call it directly AFTER calling `connect()`, it prints this:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Use of undefined constant conn - assumed 'conn' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in <b>C:\xampp2\htdocs\database.php</b> on line <b>72</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Use of undefined constant dbhost - assumed 'dbhost' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in <b>C:\xampp2\htdocs\database.php</b> on line <b>72</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Use of undefined constant dbuser - assumed 'dbuser' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in <b>C:\xampp2\htdocs\database.php</b> on line <b>72</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Use of undefined constant dbpass - assumed 'dbpass' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in <b>C:\xampp2\htdocs\database.php</b> on line <b>72</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Use of undefined constant db - assumed 'db' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in <b>C:\xampp2\htdocs\database.php</b> on line <b>72</b><br />
test
```

and the response is `<br />`

Connect function:

```
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "root";
 $dbpass = "";
 $db = "example";
 $conn;
 function connect(){
    $GLOBALS[conn] = new mysqli($GLOBALS[dbhost], $GLOBALS[dbuser], $GLOBALS[dbpass],$GLOBALS[db]) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $GLOBALS[conn] -> error);
 }
```

Comment: the php function `does_code_match` should `return` a value as you already have an `echo` when you call the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referencing array keys, you *must* enclose them in quotes, change your function to the following:

```
function connect(){
    $GLOBALS['conn'] = new mysqli($GLOBALS['dbhost'], $GLOBALS['dbuser'], $GLOBALS['dbpass'],$GLOBALS['db']) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $GLOBALS['conn'] -> error);
 }
```

Also, in general, this is a strange way of storing global variables, you should look into using the `$_ENV` array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery to the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "database.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: ({
        code: code_entered,
    }),
    context: this,
    success : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        //OPTIONAL_FUNCTION_TO_DO_SOMETHING_WITH_THE_RESPONSE(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR);
        //OPTIONAL_FUNCTION_TO_DO_SOMETHING_WITH_THE_ERROR(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

Then change your PHP to the following:

```
 if(isset($_POST['code'])){
    does_code_match($_POST['code']);
    //no need to call echo again
 }

 function does_code_match($code){
     connect();
    $sql = 'select * from emailstobeverified where email=';
    $sql .= "'" . $_SESSION['email'] . "'";
    $sql .= ' and verification_code=';
    $sql .= $code;
    $sql .= ';';
    error_log('Adding code to be verified with query: ' . $sql);
    $count = query($sql)->num_rows;
    disconnect();
    //I can't speak for the above code, I'm assuming it works.

    error_log("CODE MATCHES? "  . $count);
    error_log(json_encode($count));
    //Not sure why you're doing this, but I assume it's for testing only

    echo json_encode($count);
    exit;
    //Once you've outputted, make sure nothing else happens
 }
```

What kind of stuff do you see in your `console.log(response);` output? Once you start developing your environment, you will probably start to send back an *array* of responses instead of just a value.

Comment: I copy/pasted this. the php function is called and then it exits, but now there's no response. console.log doesnt print any output, but the value I echo is still 1.

Comment: errorThrown: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at m.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Pc (jquery.min.js:4)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)`

Comment: Have a look at your developer console (F12), do you see the AJAX call? What is returned from PHP? It seems like PHP is returning an error message. (I noticed I accidentally left `ajax.php` in the code, instead of changing it your `database.php` file name)

Comment: I changed it to database.php after I pasted it.  IN the developer console there’s no output from the Ajax call.  I don’t know what PHP is returning as a result.

Comment: Made an edit to the post. There seems to be a problem with the `connect()` call.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `connect()` and `disconnect()` methods, what framework is that from, because it's not vanilla PHP.

Comment: I added what the function does in the main post above

Comment: Please check to ensure that your SQL query completes successfully, then review the data coming back from your AJAX call, is it as expected?

Comment: The SQL query is fine. the value of `$count` is 1. However what I found is that before calling `connect()`, anything that I send back as a response is fine. It prints that string. But if I let's say `echo` some string after calling `connect()`, it just gives me HTML code as a response

Comment: Ah, I just what's up, your `connect()` function is messed up. :-) I will answer separately.

Answer (score 0):

just `echo $count`

```
$count = query($sql)->num_rows;
disconnect();
echo $count;
```

If you encode the count, on the receiving end, you will have to decode the json first.

Comment: I tried just returning text by setting `dataType="text"`. Then i `echo strval($count)` and it's still just printing `<br />`

Comment: just write `die("test"); ` right after `function does_code_match($code){` and let me know what it does

Comment: Now it's printing "test" in the console

Comment: right after  `$sql .= ';';`   write `die(query($sql)->num_rows);` and tell me what it does

Comment: it does not print anything that time. It says `RESPONSE: <br />` (I edited `function(response)` to do: `console.log("RESPONSE: " + response)`.

Comment: that means there is zero count.. echo $sql...copy and execute that query and check response

Comment: I ran the same script without `die` line you mentioned, and in the `error_log` of PHP, it says "CODE MATCHES? 1" (break) "1". So count is equal to 1. On the last line in the PHP function I write `echo $count` and it prints 1.

Comment: remove all the lines of `error_log` just write `die($count);` after `$count = query($sql)->num_rows;
`

Comment: response is `<br />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192513/discussion-between-andrew-kor-and-danyal-sandeelo).